# Observable.Subscribe fails with InvalidProgramException on .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, .net-4.5

I just started to learn [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx). And I got `InvalidProgramException` when trying to subscribe to observable that I got from event. Here is complete code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    var observable = Observable.FromEventPattern<MouseEventHandler, MouseEventArgs>(
                              h => this.MouseMove += h, h => this.MouseMove -= h);
    observable.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine("hello"));
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Exception details:

```
InvalidProgramException: "Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program."
    at System.Reactive.Concurrency.CurrentThreadScheduler.Schedule[TState](TState state, TimeSpan dueTime, Func`3 action)
    at System.Reactive.Concurrency.LocalScheduler.Schedule[TState](TState state, Func`3 action)
    at System.Reactive.Producer`1.SubscribeRaw(IObserver`1 observer, Boolean enableSafeguard)
    at System.Reactive.Producer`1.Subscribe(IObserver`1 observer)
    at System.ObservableExtensions.Subscribe[T](IObservable`1 source, Action`1 onNext)
    at FunWithReactiveUI.MainWindow..ctor() in c:\...
```

So what I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions? Thanks.

I use [Rx 2.0.21114](https://nuget.org/packages/Rx-Main/2.0.21114), .Net Framework 4.5. On 4.0 it works fine.

**Edit:**

I also got same exception with this simple code. `Subscribe` fails on .net 4.5 in debug mode.

```
Observable.Return(1).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem, so I'll just offer some general advice:

- You probably shouldn't be subscribing to events on controls before they are initialized. `InitializeComponent();` should always be the first line in the constructor or there shall be weirdness of seven kinds.
- `InvalidProgramException` is sometimes encountered when the attached debugger is acting up. Consider using `Trace` or `Console` instead of `Debug`.
- And most importantly, check the project references. .Net 4.0 and 4.5 use two different versions of Rx. If you referenced Rx through Nuget, changing the target framework won't change the Rx references, afaik. Newer Rx uses Portable libraries/platform enlightments/composition so you should be careful in ensuring that the project references all the correct assemblies.

Comment: Well, without debugging it works fine, thank you.

Comment: @2kay Although it lies in the realm of magic, sometimes a clean/rebuild/reboot also does the trick.